# SQL query - two select to one

Tags: mysql, sql, select, merge

How can I merge these two selects to one? As a result, I want column "POJ", "locked POJ" and "EV".

```
SELECT COUNT(VC) AS 'POJ', F.F_C.VC AS 'EV' FROM
F.F_D  LEFT JOIN F.F_C ON F.F_D.col_id = F.F_C.id
LEFT JOIN F.F_Z_D ON F.F_D.id = F.F_Z_D.id
where createdTime >= '2021-05-01' and createdTime <= '2022-05-31' and tTemplate = 'ZS' GROUP BY F.F_C.VC;

SELECT COUNT(VC) AS 'locked POJ', F.F_C.VC AS 'EV' FROM
F.F_D LEFT JOIN F.F_C ON F.F_D.col_id = F.F_C.id
LEFT JOIN F.F_Z_D ON F.F_D.id = F.F_Z_D.id
where createdTime >= '2021-05-01' and createdTime <= '2022-05-31' and tTemplate = 'ZS' and locked = 1 GROUP BY F.F_C.VC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(VC) AS POJ, SUM(locked = 1) AS `locked POJ`, F.F_C.VC AS EV
FROM F.F_D
LEFT JOIN F.F_C ON F.F_D.col_id = F.F_C.id
LEFT JOIN F.F_Z_D ON F.F_D.id = F.F_Z_D.id
WHERE createdTime BETWEEN '2021-05-01' AND '2022-05-31' AND tTemplate = 'ZS'
GROUP BY F.F_C.VC;
```

Note that the only difference between the two queries is that the second one has the additional criterion `locked = 1` in the `WHERE` clause.  We can remove it and use the first query, along with a conditional count.

Comment: hi, I am not the OP but out of curiosity, how does SUM(locked =1) work?  I mean result-wise. its a very interesting approach

Comment: @Demeteor: `locked = 1` is a condition that return either 1 if true or 0 if false. You can sum up how many times the condition was true with `sum(locked = 1)`

Comment: @Demeteor MySQL, SQLite, BigQuery, and maybe a few other databases support this syntax.  This is called summing a boolean expression.

Comment: Thanks for the answer both of you.  I did not know if it existed. gotta test it on SQL-Server and see if this can work there as well

Comment: @Demeteor It won't work on SQL Server or Oracle, sorry.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah just tested it. but still I learned something new so its still cool ^^

Comment: 'Using SUM(CASE WHEN locked=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ...` could have been more explicit and portable.

Comment: @tinazmu ... well while you're at, your version can be made more terse: `COUNT(CASE WHEN locked = 1 THEN 1 END)`

Comment: Haha. My intention was to make the logic  more obvious not more terse, but it may have the opposite effect.